# NGINX disable cache only for target files

Tags: nginx, caching, http-headers

I need to edit an existing NGINX configuration to selectively disable the cache for specific files: a target `activity.js` file and the `index.html`.

Would the rules below respect the correct `location` priority and allow to selectively disable the cache as wished?

```
http {

  server {
    listen {{port}};

    server_name localhost;    
    root /home/vcap/app/dist;

    location / {

      alias /home/vcap/app/dist/;

      # ENABLE CACHE on root level
      add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
      add_header Cache-Control 'private, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=31536000';
       
       # DISABLE CACHE for activity.js
       location /b2b/activity/activity.js {
         alias /home/vcap/app/dist/;
        
         add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
         add_header Cache-Control 'private no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
         if_modified_since off;
         expires off;
         etag off;
        }

       # DISABLE CACHE for index.html
       location = /b2b/activity/index.html {
         alias /home/vcap/app/dist/; # <- Not sure if alias and the exact match work fine together

         add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
         add_header Cache-Control 'private no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
         if_modified_since off;
         expires off;
         etag off;
       }

    # all the rest can be cached
    location /b2b/activity {
      if ($query_string ~ ../) {
        return 400;
      }
      alias /home/vcap/app/dist/;
      index index.html index.htm Default.htm;

      try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri/ ;
  }
 }

}
```